# Report Title as a ReadOnly parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, readonly

I've tried searching all over the internet for anything close to what I'm looking for and have been very unsuccessful. What I am wanting to do is to create a parameter in SSRS that shows the name of the report in the parameters section. But I want it to only be a label, instead of having a drop down box. I know if you take away the available values it makes it editable. If there is even a way to make a default value read only without having to have available values I think that would be okay as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters are not meant for this purpose. Even if you building the parameters with the RDlObjectModel the report parameter object doesn't even allow the parameter to be read only. I suggest to write your own custom interface to show headers and use a report viewer control.

Comment: Thank you for your response, this is the information I was looking for.